# Problem with data <0 not being removed from data set (despite seemly correct code?)

Tags: r, subset, hour

This is my dataset (called cc)

```
Counter Date    Hour    Counts
1296    02/05/2008  0      2
1296    02/05/2008  100    0
1296    02/05/2008  200    2
1296    02/05/2008  300    0
1296    02/05/2008  400    1
1296    02/05/2008  500    6
1296    02/05/2008  600    6
1296    02/05/2008  700    45
1296    02/05/2008  800    106
1296    02/05/2008  900    43
1296    02/05/2008  1000   33
1296    02/05/2008  1100   -4
1296    02/05/2008  1200   -4
1296    02/05/2008  1300   56
1296    02/05/2008  1400   45
1296    02/05/2008  1500   49
1296    02/05/2008  1600   88
1296    02/05/2008  1700   124
1296    02/05/2008  1800   91
1296    02/05/2008  1900   42
1296    02/05/2008  2000   33
1296    02/05/2008  2100   13
1296    02/05/2008  2200   9
1296    02/05/2008  2300   8
```

I have recently asked a question on how to subset my data if the data met specific criteria between two hours of a day (see question here [subset data for a day if data between two hours of the day meets criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582189/subset-data-for-a-day-if-data-between-two-hours-of-the-day-meets-criteria)) which worked fine.

My follow up question is this,

Any counts less than 0 needs to be taken out of the data set as this is an error. For days where there is >0 between 600 and 2200 (so if there is 0 counts at 900 this would mean the day isn’t included in the subset but if there are counts between 600 and 2200 but a 0 at 200 then the whole day is still counted) my code works fine but there are a couple of hours of seemingly random days where I have -4 data included in the output (in the example 1100 and 1200). **I can’t see any reason why these minus numbers should still be in the data set as the rest of the minus numbers are removed,** I’ve also checked my original data and there is no difference in the formatting. Any help would be much appreciated as I haven’t found anything else to help while searching online and i believe the code provided in my last question was correct.

Here is the code I have been using (which all works find apart from the random -4’s for a couple of days).

```
#code to make only 600 hrs to 2200 hrs over 0 #
#########################################

TDF <- subset(cc, Hour>=600 & Hour<=2200) 
# get dates where there are no hours with zero count 
dates2 <- subset(aggregate(counts~Date,TDF,prod),counts>=0)$Date  
DF3 <- subset(cc,Date %in% dates2) 

#i then make the counts daily (not shown in example)#
###########################################
daily=subset(DF3)
daily$Date <- as.Date(daily$Date, "%d/%m/%Y") 
town=aggregate(counts ~ Date, daily, sum)
```

Thank you in advance for your help,
Katie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aggregating with the `prod` function and then checking that the result is >0 , you should not be surprised when -4 * -4 is GT 0.

Comment: Ah right i see! Thanks @DWin, i'm an R newbie and just couldnt figure out why that wasnt working. Would i be best off adding a short bit of code before i create DF3 which excludes <0 or is there a neater way of doing it? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You could easily add "& Count >0" to the subset argument, so it looks like: TDF <- subset(cc, Hour>=600 & Hour<=2200 & Count >0)